# Javascript - Change button text doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following piece of code I need in order to update a bootstrap button when a collapsed  is opened or closed. However the icon part is updating but impossible to get the button text updated and I have no idea why.

My javascript level is very low and I'm simply using part of code I might find on SOF or anywhere else on internet.

**Javascript**

```
$('#more-properties').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
  var icon = document.getElementById("icon-more-properties");
  icon.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-angle-down pr-2');

  var btn = document.getElementById("btn-more-properties");
  btn.textContent('More properties');
});
$('#more-properties').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
  var icon = document.getElementById("icon-more-properties");
  icon.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-angle-up pr-2');

  var btn = document.getElementById("btn-more-properties");
  btn.textContent('Less properties');
});
```

**Bootstrap button**

```
<div class="col-12 text-center" id="btn-div">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-dark shadow-none collapsed" id="btn-more-properties" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#more-properties" style="border-radius: 0 !important;">
    <i id="icon-more-properties" class="fas fa-angle-down pr-2"></i>More properties</button>
</div>
```

Does anyone can tell me why it is not working ? I can't find any similar issue on iternet.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Does this link provide you an answer?
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_collapse_events&stacked=h

Comment: Are you sure you don't have more than one element in the page with `id="btn-more-properties"`? If so, that is not allowed. **`id`, at all times and cost, must be unique, per-document.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that `textContent` is not a function but a property,
so instead of calling it you need to assign the value to it:

```
btn.textContent = 'Less properties';
```

Hope this helps

Comment: BTW if you're already using jQuery, instead of `getElementById` and `textContent` you can simply `$("#btn-more-properties").text("...")`.

Comment: @mbojko He's forced to use jQuery because those events are Bootstrap jQuery events. Replacing native API with jQuery in 2021 is definitely a *downgrade*.

Comment: I just tried and indeed it is updating the text thank you, however the text replace also the icon. How should I do to keep it and update the text at the same time ? I was originally thinking about changing the whole html code inside the <div< by pre-writing it in the script and then apply  '.html' ; '.innerHtml'vor other but it is simply not working as I expected.

Comment: I would suggest for you to wrap the button text on a span and manipulate the span textContent, i.e: `<button {buttonProperties}><i {iconProperties}></icon><span>More Properties</span></button>` and then from javascript you just get i.e: `document.querySelector('#btn-more-properties span').textContent = 'whatever you like'` and this way you wont overwrite the icon on button

Comment: It worked perfectly thank you !